# Compiling issue: undefined reference to pthread_cleanup_push_defer_np() and pthread_cleanup_pop_restore_np()

Tags: c, compiler-errors, pthreads

I am currently writing a C program with threads and I make use of `pthread_cleanup_push_defer_np()` and  `pthread_cleanup_pop_restore_np()`. Provided that:

- I have included `pthread.h`;
- I am compiling with `-pthread` option;
- I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and using `gcc` version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1);

when compiling I get back a nasty undefined reference error to the above mentioned functions and I can't figure out why. I have tried to take a look into `pthread.h` and it seems those two functions are commented out, so I am wondering whether I need to enable them in some way or use some other kind of options. I've read the manual pages and google it up but I can't find a solution, so I would appreciate a little help. Here it is a snippet:

```
    void *start_up(void *arg)
    {
        char *timestamp;
             // ... code ...
        timestamp = get_current_timestamp("humread"); 
        pthread_cleanup_push_defer_np(free, timestamp);
            // ... some other code
        pthread_cleanup_pop_restore_np(1);
           // ... more code ...
    }
```

I compile with

```
gcc -pthread -o server *.c
```

Comment: Show your linker invocation.

Comment: @KerrekSB I have added the compile command I use.

Comment: Try using `#define _GNU_SOURCE` at the top of the your source file.

Comment: @BlueMoon: I was thinking that, too, but the manual doesn't say that you have to do this. And it shouldn't even compile if the symbol wasn't declared.

Comment: Add also `-W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. You should have caught a missing function declaration *much* earlier in the process.

Comment: @KerrekSB `*_np` stands for "non portable" and my implementation does require it (glibc 2.17) and [GNU specific feature test macro does seem to imply it's required](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html).

Comment: Additionally, most likely that symbol should be a macro anyway; thus there are most likely _compilation_ warnings you're not showing us?

Comment: @mnunberg thank you for you help, BlueMoon fix has sorted out my issue and now it compiles with no undefined reference errors.

Comment: @KerrekSB Not sure why you are saying it shouldn't compile. Functions are external and compiler assumes it's there and only linker can find it's not there anywhere.

Comment: @BlueMoon: If the feature macro is missing, the very function declaration shouldn't exist. But I forgot that function declarations are optional in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual of [pthread_cleanup_push_defer_np and pthread_cleanup_pop_restore_np](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push_defer_np.3.html) say these two (non portable) functions are GNU extensions and are enabled 
by defining `_GNU_SOURCE`:

```
   Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

       pthread_cleanup_push_defer_np(), pthread_cleanup_pop_defer_np():
           _GNU_SOURCE
```

This results in linker error (as opposed to compile time error) because your compiler is pre-C99 (or you are compiling in pre-C99 mode) and assumes these functions return `int` by default.

The rule *functions-return-int* if no prototype is present has been removed since C99. Enabling more compiler switches can help you with better diagnostics.